# ORA-01008 : Not all variables bound with nulls

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm creating a query and I cannot seem to get beyond the `Not all variables bound` error in Oracle

As best as I can tell, everything looks correct. What am I missing?

Code obfuscated a bit to protect the innocent...

```
OracleCommand execCmd = new OracleCommand();

OracleParameter outParam =
        new OracleParameter("ID", OracleType.Int32);
outParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
outParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
execCmd.CommandText = "insert into o " +
        "(A, B, " +
        "C, D, E, " +
        "F, G, H, I, " +
        "J, K) " +
        "VALUES (:A, :B, :C, :D, :E, " +
        ":F, :G, :H, :I, :J, :K) " +
        "RETURNING O_ID INTO :ID";
execCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("A", og.N);
execCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("B", DBNull.Value);
execCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("C", DBNull.Value);
execCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("D", og.A);
execCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("E",
    og.A1 + " " + og.A2 + " " + og.A3 +
    " " + og.C);
execCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("F", DBNull.Value);
execCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("G", DBNull.Value);
execCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("H", og.Cs);
execCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("I", ss);
execCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("J", DBNull.Value);
execCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("K", "N");
execCmd.Parameters.Add(outParam);
conn.executeCommand(execCmd, trx);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve this eventually. Turned out that one of my strings was in fact null, and there's a bug in this version of `OracleCommand` (which is marked as deprecated) that causes it to drop null parameters. The solution for me was to run a fixup function before executing.

Also, as others stated, the order DOES matter. So, that needs to be correct as well.

Here's what worked for me, calling it right before execution:

```
private void PopulateNullParameters(OracleCommand cmd)
{
    foreach (OracleParameter p in cmd.Parameters)
    {
        if (p.Value == null)
        {
            p.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Worked for me too!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing a parameter for ID, in this last line:

```
"RETURNING ORGANIZATION_ID INTO :ID";
```

Also, based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422032/oracle-ora-01008-not-all-variables-bound-error-w-parameters), it appears that the OracleCommand object binds the parameters by position, so if your parameters are out of order, you might want to look at using the [BindByName](http://oradim.blogspot.com/2007/08/odpnet-tip-bind-variables-and.html) property:

```
using(OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand()) {
    ...
    cmd.BindByName = true;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's actually declared at the top, and added at the bottom, in order/position, so `BindByName` isn't the issue I don't think.  Curiously, I seem to be missing that property though...

Answer (score 0):

Try to precede your parameter name with `:` colon

e.g.

```
  execCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":NAME", org.Name);
  execCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":EDP", DBNull.Value);
  execCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":EDD", DBNull.Value);
  execCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":ACRONYM", org.Acronym);    
  ....
```